# One word for experiencing a place or event through their description without being physically going to that place or event?

Tags: single-word-requests

One word for experiencing a place or event through someone else's explanation without being physically going to that place or event?

Comment: Imagination? Empathy? Fantasy?

Comment: Virtual, secondhand, vicarious

Answer (score 14):

The word you are looking for is "vicarious," which is defined online as "experienced in the imagination through the feelings or actions of another person."  "His description of his vacation was so vivid, I experienced it *vicariously*."